# Somar colunas DataTable C# com Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Tenho um `DataTable` que contém uma coluna chamada `SubTotal`. Gostaria de somar o valor total desta coluna.

Testei alguns exemplos:

```
object sumObject;
sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Amount)", "");
```

Este também:

```
this.LabelControl.Text = datatable.AsEnumerable()
.Sum( x => x.Field<int>( "Amount" ) )
.ToString();
```

Porem não deram certo. Como fazer isso?

Comment: É isso, precisa descobrir o que está fazendo errado, mas como não postou um [mcve] fica complicado pra gente ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nada de errado, deve verificar se a DataTable esta preenchida corretamente. Segue exemplo pra ajudar.

```
        //cria DataTable
        var dt = new DataTable("teste");
        dt.Columns.Add("valor", typeof(decimal));

        //cria valores teste
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var r = dt.NewRow();
            r["valor"] = i;
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }

        //Faz a soma via Linq
        var mostrar = dt
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Sum(s => s.Field<decimal>("valor"))
            .ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(mostrar);
```

Comment: Cara, obrigado, o meu erro estava justamento no tipo do field. Estava preenchido corretamente o datatable porem estava fazendo confusão com o tipo do field.

Comment: Muito útil essa última parte do código.